# How to make one program use a specific network card?

Tags: internet, networking

At work they have disabled the use of P2P networks such as bittorrent. (Causes too many open connections according to the admins.)

Is there a way to let all programs, except Transmission use `eth0` and Transmission use `usb0`?

Answer (score 2):

Some programs let you specify what IP address they bind to. Unfortunately, Transmission is not one of them.

If you don't mind using Deluge (another bit torrent client), you could install it. Then open it, Open the Edit menu, click Preferences, then click Network in the sidebar. In the interface field, put the IP address that usb0 has.  (You can find this out by runnning `ifconfig usb0` in a terminal).